# SQl query transform rows into column

Tags: php, sql

I have following code,and its work well. I just have problem with output data from database,because output is wrong.

Output is:

```
email : admin@admin.com
email : 120
```

or

```
email : admin@admin.com
email : click
email : 28
```

Now my question is,,how can i change word "email" in output to some other word.

Here is my databse:

ID | entry_id |  field_id  |  slug  | Value

---

1     1           fld_7555401     text      120
2     1          fld_7555502     email     admin@admin.com
3      2            fld_7555401     text      14
4      2            fld_7555402     email     admin@admin.com
5      2            fld_7555403     send      click
6      3            fld_7555401     text      28
7      3            fld_7555402     email     admin@admin.com
8      3            fld_7555403     send      unkown

```
  <?php
  get_header();
  include 'connection.php';
 $theentry_id = 0;
  if ( isset( $_GET['entry_id'] ) ) {
     $theentry_id = $_GET['entry_id'];
   }
  echo '<div style="max-width:500px; padding-right:30px;  padding-left:30px; margin:auto;">';
  if ( $theentry_id > 0) {
    //connect to db

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "select slug ,value  from wp_cf_form_entry_values WHERE entry_id = ? order 
  BY slug ");
        $stmt->bind_param("d", $theentry_id );
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "email : " ,$row['value'] , "<br>";
                            }
            }

  } else {
    echo "Error,no data";
 }
 echo "</div>";
 get_footer();
 ?>
```

Comment: In the `while`-loop where you echo the row results just change `email` to something different.

Comment: `echo $row['slug'];` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you are trying to not just output `email` but instead the description of what it is?

So in the `while`-loop where you `echo "email : ..."` instead of `email` just use the slug or however it is called. Like this:

```
echo "{$row['slug']} : {$row['value']}"; //text : 120 , email : admin@admin.com, send : click
```

Comment: Thank you for reply,your code work,but output is :email : admin@admin.comsend : clicktext : zxc..i'm trying to have each value in new line,with description.as of now all is in same line

Comment: @jolka Just add `\n` after the last curly bracket '}'